# How I can fix the error to assign variable value in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I had an error when I'd tried to create procedure to display data
Here is error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
>    := . ) , @ % default character
>    The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spemp94_display(
p_hireyear VARCHAR2(4),
c_emp94 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
p_hireyear := '1994';
OPEN c_emp94 FOR
    SELECT last_name, hire_date
    FROM employees
    WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'yyyy') = p_hireyear;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this parameter definition

```
p_hireyear VARCHAR2(4)
```

It is not allowed to define the size of a variable when defining procedure arguments.

Simply change it to

```
p_hireyear VARCHAR2
```

Also, since `p_hireyear` is an `IN` parameter( the default if neither `IN` or `OUT` explicitly specified), you can't assign a value to it.

You would receive

> PLS-00363: expression 'P_HIREYEAR' cannot be used as an assignment
>   target

It should be assigned while passing the procedure arguments.

```
declare cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
 spemp94_display('1994',cur); -- specify the value here not inside the procedure.
END;
/
```